# How to retreive paticular data from dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
product_list = {'Name': ['Milk, 2 Litres', 'Bread', 'Sugar', 'Apple'], 'Price': ['2.0', '3.5', '3.0', '4.5'], 'weight': ['2', '0.6', '2.8', '4.2']} <br/>
Now the Question is <br/>
class Weightcheck:<br/>
    def bag_products(product_list):<br/>
       bag_list = []<br/>
        non_bag_items = []<br/>
        MAX_BAG_WEIGHT = 5.0<br/>

        for product in product_list:
            if product.weight > MAX_BAG_WEIGHT:
                product_list.remove(product)
                non_bag_items.append(product)
```

Whenever I pass an argument to the function as,

```
demo = Weightcheck()
demo.bag_products(product_list)
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: bag_products() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Could you remove the html ‘<br>’ tags?

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add `self` in `bag_products`.

replace

```
def bag_products(product_list):
```

with

```
def bag_products(self, product_list):
```

*Edit as per comments*

```
product_list = {'Name': ['Milk, 2 Litres', 'Bread', 'Sugar', 'Apple'], 'Price': ['2.0', '3.5', '3.0', '4.5'], 'weight': ['2', '0.6', '2.8', '4.2']}

class Weightcheck:
    def bag_products(self, product_list):
        bag_list = []
        non_bag_items = []
        MAX_BAG_WEIGHT = 5.0

        for w in product_list['weight']:
            if float(w) > MAX_BAG_WEIGHT:
                bag_list.append(w)
                non_bag_items.append(w)
        print(bag_list)
        print(non_bag_items)

demo = Weightcheck()
demo.bag_products(product_list)
```

Comment: no it didn't work still gave me error as AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'weight'

Comment: That's  a different error. You probably need to iterate using `product['weight']`

Comment: product_list is a dictionary, if you iterate on it like:  for product in product_list you will iterate over all the key

Comment: and how can I do that please help @Rakesh

Comment: then what is the proper solution for my problem @bboumend

Comment: I think you better should have a list of dictionary with one dictionary for each product like this : product_list = [
            {'Name': 'Milk, 2 Litres', 'Price': '2.0', 'weight': '2',},
            {'Name': 'Bread', 'Price': '3.5', 'weight': '0.6'}
        ]

Comment: @NICK. Updated snippet. Please check if that is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Using a list of dictionary should be better

```
product_list = [
    {'Name': 'Milk, 2 Litres', 'Price': '2.0', 'weight': '2',},
    {'Name': 'Bread', 'Price': '3.5', 'weight': '0.6'}
]


class Weightcheck:
    def bag_products(self, product_list):
        non_bag_items = []
        MAX_BAG_WEIGHT = 5.0

        for product in product_list:
            if float(product['weight']) > MAX_BAG_WEIGHT:
                product_list.remove(product)
                non_bag_items.append(product)
```